# Как получить только одно поле обьектов в массиве ? (Java)

Tags: java

К примеру есть ArrayList c обьектами а1, а2, а3. У обьектов есть поля в1, в2, в3. И вот мне нужно вывести на экран только поле в1 каждого обьекта. Как это сделать ? Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: День добрый. Не нужно писать ответ со "спасибо". Если какой-то ответ вам помог, лучше отметьте его как принятый (галочка слева от ответа) ^__^

Answer (score 3):

Если экран это консоль, то вот так:

```
someList.forEach(obj -> System.out.println(obj.getB1()));
```

Какой вопрос такой и ответ.

Comment: Если честно я не понял. Можно какой-то другой способ ?

Comment: @Никита Тогда вам следует почитать литературу. Либо обновить вопрос, если что либо не понятно.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ alex safsafsd верен, но возможно необходимо пояснение.
Если не использовать java 8 :

```
AObject a1 = new AObject();
AObject a2 = new AObject();
AObject a3 = new AObject();
// использование сеттеров или конструкторов для задания параметров
List<AObject> aObjects = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(a1, a2, a3));
for (AObject aObject : aObjects) {
    System.out.println(aObject.getB1());
}
```

Если ваш объект выглядит примерно так.

```
class AObject{
    private int b1;
    private int b2;
    private int b3;

    public int getB1() {
        return b1;
    }

    public void setB1(int b1) {
        this.b1 = b1;
    }

    public int getB2() {
        return b2;
    }

    public void setB2(int b2) {
        this.b2 = b2;
    }

    public int getB3() {
        return b3;
    }

    public void setB3(int b3) {
        this.b3 = b3;
    }
}
```